# How to fix " W503 line break before binary operator" without getting W504?

Tags: python, pylint

Using `pylint` 2.7.1 I am having problems with the following code snippet:

```
   files = [
        filename
        for filename in os.listdir(str(repo_folder))
        if filename.lower().startswith("license")
        or filename.lower().startswith("copying")  # line 197
    ]
```

When running pylint I get the warning

```
code.py:197:13: W503 line break before binary operator
```

when I change the code to the following:

```
    files = [
        filename
        for filename in os.listdir(str(repo_folder))
        if filename.lower().startswith("license") or
        filename.lower().startswith("copying")
    ]
```

I get the warning

```
code.py:196:55: W504 line break after binary operator
```

This looks like a bug to me. I cannot possibly see a way to neither have the line-break after nor before the operator (when you have to use a line break).

Maybe this version of `pylint` is to be used for Quantum Computing?

Comment: W503 is wrong, disable it. Afaik both of these aren't enabled by default, because they contradict eachother.

Comment: Thanks - now I have to figure out why disabling this warning does not work ... B ut this is another question